# Location Finding in iPhone SDk

Tags: iphone, gps, location

Can we get the a rough location of iPhone without using GPS. 
Something region in the iPhone settings will also be helpful.?
Any Idea ?

Comment: Any reason not using the GPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free web apis are available to detect the location using the IP address.

http://www.ipaddressapi.com/

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

By using these API you can determine the nearest city.

Comment: In small countries, IP lookup services don't work well since ISP servers are registered and running their servers in one city, while providing internet to users in other cities. My experience in Israel is that 3 million internet users get IP lookups that say all of them are located in 2-3 cities, when many major cities are never returned correctly from an ip lookup.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the [core location framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007123), it will look for location by using any method of three: GPS, cell tower triangulation, and wi-fi positioning. This means that all iOS devices can get their location.

There is no reason for you not to use this.

However, you did say 'something region in the iphone settings'. This code can get the country name:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *countryName = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode]];
```

For more info on [NSLocale](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html), see Apple's [locales programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFLocales/CFLocales.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000181i).

Comment: It was Exactly What I needed (The NSLocale one) Thanks First For Understanding my Stupid Question Then For the Reply